# Ubuntu 12.04 mdadm inactive

Tags: raid, mdadm

For a while now, my RAID 5 has ceased to work. Everytime I tried "madm --detail /dev/md127", its states all the drive and drive info, but that two of the drives have been removed.

After some restarts, doing the same thing, i am getting /dev/md127 does not appear to be active.

When I go into DiskUtil, I can see all 6 Hard Drives healthy and present, and i can see the Raid 5 at the bottom under Multi-disk Devices. However, the Raid says 0.0kb, and is not active.

Please help and let me know how to proceed from here. I would really like to avoid rebuilding the RAID, especially because all 6 drives seem to be healthy and present. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with my raid6 array with 12 drives and 2 spares for a total of 14 drives. I got the following error:

```
mdadm: /dev/md20 assembled from 8 drives and 2 spares - not enough to start the array
```

So I did the following:

```
sudo mdadm -S /dev/md20
mdadm: stopped /dev/md20
```

Then I got the array uuid:

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdi1
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md20 --force --uuid=c28cf9bd:29fad7e9:1721f24c:e1059626
```

Then I received the following message:

`mdadm: /dev/md20 has been started with 12 drives and 2 spares`